# htaccess rewrite condition redirect to root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am just simply trying to redirect several pages to the root domain and unsure why its failing, nothing happens.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /category/uncategorized/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /2014/12/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=19
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=18
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=5
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=20
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=72
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=6
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=10
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=15
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=14
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=16
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=17
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=99
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=44
RewriteRule http://domain.com? [L,R=301]
```

The WP rewrites are in this same .htaccess but no change if I remove them.

Comment: The first two aren't query strings. For the others it'd be easier to combine the ids into an `OR`d regex. Plus you need a `RewriteCond` per rule, otherwise the whole lot will be `AND`d together, unless you say otherwise by specifying `[OR]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should work. Make sure it's in the `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule category/uncategorized/? http://domain.com? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule 2014/12/? http://domain.com? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=([56]|1[4-9]|20|44|72|99)
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Why would `category/uncategorized` be part of the `REQUEST_URI` *and* the `QUERY_STRING`? Same goes for the month archive URI.

Comment: @MikeAnthony they wouldn't, thanks for pointing out. Dodgy cut/paste job caused that

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** @arco444's answer will work for you (and is indeed a better answer), but it is essential that you try and understand exactly what is happening if you want to use it.

**Option 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/uncategorized/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2014/12/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=19 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=18 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=5 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=20 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=72 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=10 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=15 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=14 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=16 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=17 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=99 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=44
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com? [L,R=301]
```

The main thing here is the `[OR]` flag. In your original code, you were basically saying that *all* conditions had to be met. Remember that the last condition should not have the `[OR]`.

Secondly, you were using `QUERY_STRING` to check for `category/...`, but that has nothing to do with the query string, which appear after the `?`. So, I have change that to `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Also, your `RewriteRule` did not have a URI to match against. I have added a `^` before the domain name to say that it should match everything (that is, provided the conditions have been met).

**Option 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/uncategorized/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2014/12/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=(5|6|10|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|44|72|99)
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com? [L,R=301]
```

Here, I have simplified the query string check. We now use one condition to check for different attachment IDs.

You could probably simplify this even further, but the purpose of my answer is to let you know where you went wrong, and where things can be simplified a little.

Comment: This is great, one problem I have the first request for /category/uncategorized/ redirects to http://domain.com/uncategorized/ not just domain.com  Everything else looks good Thank you